# What does Zend Server Community Edition install for you?

Tags: php, apache, zend-server

[This page](http://www.zend.com/products/server-ce/downloads) says Zend Server Community Edition installs a "Complete PHP Stack that includes ZF". What does that mean?  Does it install Apache?  MySql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I got my answer while taking a chance and installing Zend Server, Here is the following from the Readme

```
What is Installed?
 - PHP-Zend Server provides a complete PHP stack that can be controlled by the Administration Interface
 - MySQL Database
 - Apache Web server
In addition, the following components are also installed:
Zend components that are installed and enabled:
 - Zend Debugger - The Zend Debugger component enables remote debugging of PHP scripts using Zend Studio or PDT.
 - Zend Optimizer+ - The Zend Optimizer+ component speeds up PHP execution through opcode caching and optimization.
 - Zend Data Cache - The Zend Data Cache component provides a set of PHP functions for improving performance by storing data in the cache.
 - Zend Framework - An open source framework for developing Web applications and Web services with PHP.
 - PHPmyAdmin - A popular open-source management tool for handling MySql Database over a Web interface.
Additional Zend Server features that are not included in the Community Edition:
 - Zend Monitor - The Zend Monitor component is integrated into the runtime environment and serves as an alerting and collection mechanism for early detection of PHP script problems.
 - Zend Page Cache - The Zend Page Cache component is used for caching the entire output of PHP scripts without changing the PHP code.
 - Job Queue Component - The Jobs Component is used to streamline offline processing of PHP scripts.
- Zend Code Tracing - Code Tracing enables real-time execution flow recording in Production Environments.
```